# How to Run my playN game in production mode locally?

Tags: html, gwt, playn

I want to run my playN game in production mode as the development mode is too slow to test. I am not able to click and get the response for buttons and it updates very slow in dev mode. I have read that substituting the IP of the link with "localhost" will do. But even after i have done the same, It is too slow like before.

I need to run the html version only. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try running it having the test-html profile active. From PlayN's [getting started](http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GettingStarted#Running_via_Maven) page:

```
cd playn-samples/showcase
mvn clean package
mvn test -Ptest-html
```

Then just browse to http://localhost:8080/ once Jetty has started. I find it significantly faster than development mode. Just substitute the showcase with your own application.

Comment: Thank You. I have followed this. It seems working. But unfortunately I have lot of compile errors and when i browse http://localhost:8080/ it shows blank page. I hope you can help.

Comment: When i compile using GwtCompile, It shows errors for all the JSon related stuffs and lot more. We are using playN.json(). is there anything I have to do extra to compile it correctly?

Comment: I've had exactly the same problem, it took me hours to locate the issue. In my case, the assets path was incorrect. Take a good solid look at your browser JS console (Chrome dev tools), and you should see a 404. Recheck your path prefix: platform.assets().setPathPrefix("my/path/prefix");

Comment: Hi Thank you for the support. I could remove the compiler errors. And now I ran in to the exact issue that you have mentioned in the previous comment. I am finding a 404 i.e No file found for: /myproject/myproject.nocache.js   What could be the reason? please help me. How will I find out the filepath of nocache.js