# How to resolve the playN asset path error?

Tags: gwt, playn

I am getting the following error when I run my playN project.

"No file found for: /myproject/myproject.nocache.js"

Also I am getting only a black screen in the browser.

In the MyProjectHtml.java file I am giving the path as

"platform.assets().setPathPrefix("myproject/");"

How can I resolve this problem. I am not finding any file with the name "nocache".

Note: The comment in one of my previous question's answer will be useful: [How to Run my playN game in production mode locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9976427/how-to-run-my-playn-game-in-production-mode-locally)

Thank you.

SOLVED: the resource folder under war was getting generated using eclipse compile only.I have created a source folder src/main/resources and moved all my resources package to it. Before it was under src/main/java. Now it works..! I can compile from terminal and run.

Comment: Here is my error log when i do a mvn clean and install:          [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3:compile (default-compile) on project myproject-html: Compilation failure
[ERROR] MyProjectHtml.java:[20,21] cannot access playn.core.AbstractCachingAssets
[ERROR] class file for playn.core.AbstractCachingAssets not found
[ERROR] platform.assets().setPathPrefix("myproject/");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you running the project via **Maven** (`mvn test -Ptest-html`) or as **GWT project** (`mvn gwt:run`)?

The first case should work if your path is set correctly, but running it as a GWT project has always failed for me.

I also suggest doing a `mvn clean install`, and seeing which resources are contained within your `.war` file. Your `.nocache.js` file should be in there, if not, you probably have a bigger issue (incorrect project setup).

### **Update:**

Seeing as you don't have the `.nocache.js` file in your `war` something is wrong with your Maven configuration. See if the following config has been added to your HTML pom in your plugins tags:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>prepare-package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Either way, your HTML version won't run until you see the `.nocache.js` in your `war` file. Double-check your Maven configuration with a new PlayN project, and see where there are differences.

Comment: Hi, I am using mvn clean package and then mvn test -Ptest-html to run. I did mvn clean install too. but in the target folder, either myproject-html-1.0-SNAPSHOT not the war file contains .nocache.js or even the folder myproject which is supposed to contain images forlder and other resources. So the resources folder "myproject" is not getting created. When I compile from eclipse this folder and contents are getting generated. But when i run the project using mvn test -Ptest-html, it shows black screen.

Comment: In google chrome developer tools I am getting 404 nocache.js not found, and there is no myproject resource folder found. And I have created and set up my projects exactly as it is recommended by playn or as the sample applications. the only difference is there are other dependent projects. And I am doing mvn clean install to all of them before compiling and running myproject.

Comment: Any hints? please let me know.

Comment: If the .nocache.js can't be found in your war, then something is probably wrong with your Maven configuration. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hi, I have checked all these thinks and still I am getting the same problem. When I compile from eclipse, it generates the folder myproject in the war and when I compile from terminal it doesnt generate this folder.

Comment: The same comment still applies: double-check your Maven configuration (or post it in your question).

Comment: I have created a source folder src/main/resources and moved all my resources package to it.  Before it was under src/main/java. Now it works..!  So it was about maven configuration itself.